# what is wrong with the template function parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Hi I am new to templates. Just want to know how to compile the program correctly.

```
 template<class t>
 class node{
    public: 
       t val;
       node(t v):val(v){}
 };
 template<class t>
 class stack{
   private: 
     stack *next;
     static stack *head;
     static int top;
   public:  
     void push(node *n);
     node* pop();
 };
 template<class t>
 int stack<t>::top=0;
 template<class t>
 stack<t>* stack<t>::head=NULL;
 template<class t>
 void stack<t>::push(node<t>* n)   //Error the push function is not defined properly
 {

 }


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    node<int> n1(5);
    return 0;
 }
```

The program gives error

```
  stack<t>::push' : redefinition; different basic types
     nw.cpp(14) : see declaration of 'stack<t>::push'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Head and top should not be static, otherwise you can only ever have 1 stack.

Comment: `node *n` and `node<t> * n` is not the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration:

```
void push(node *n);
```

should be:

```
void push(node<t> *n);
```

Answer (score 1):

The class template `node` needs template arguments

Use `node<t>` at :

`void push(node<t> *n);` and `node<t>* pop();` and according at implementation

Answer (score 0):

```
  public:  void push(node *n);
```

should be

```
  public:  void push(node<t> *n);
```

Answer (score 0):

`node` is a class template so its template arguments are needed even in the declaration:

```
void     push(node<n> *n);
node<t>* pop();
```

The only scenario in which you can leave the template arguments out in a parameter declaration is when the declaration appears in the class scope itself. In such a situation `node` is referred to as the *injected class name*.

Also, as the comments point out, `head` and `top` shouldn't be static data members. This inhibits the creation of independent stack instances and can cause a lot of confusion when they're being used. Instead, make them *non-static* data members so they only refer to the instance being used.